# How to change Apache 2.4 configuration from SSL support to TLS

Tags: apache, ssl, apache2.4

I have Apache 2.4 installed on Windows Server 2008 R2 (not using IIS) I currently have SSL enabled with a 2048 cert.

How can I change Apache to switch from using SSL to using TLS?

Thank you

Comment: TLS is just another name for SSL, TLS 1.0 is the same as SSL 3.1. You might better search for how to disable SSL 3.0 on apache and there are [lots of information](https://www.google.de/?q=apache%20disable%20sslv3) about this.

Comment: It is my understanding that it is a different technology as SSL3.1 is not PCI complaint any more   not sure the details but TLS is the method to use not SSL.  sorry my terms may be incorrect

Comment: TLS1.0 is different to SSL3.0 the same as TLS1.1 is different to TLS1.0. TLS1.0 is just a renamed SSL3.1. All these are versions of the same basic technology. You might want to read [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `SSLProtocol` directive in your `httpd-ssl.conf` file as below

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
```

More details can be found  [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslprotocol)

**UPDATE**

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
```

Comment: I can't find `SSLProtocol` anywhere in the httpd-ssl.conf

Comment: Where did you configure your SSL certs ? SSLProtocol should be in <VirtualHost *.443>. please check your vhost config files as well.

Comment: I have <VirtualHost *.443> inside the httpd-ssl.conf file but I can't find SSLProtocol I have also check https.conf and SSLProtocol does not exists there as well

Comment: ok, put this 'SSLEngine on SSLProtocol all -SSLv3' inside <VirtualHost *:443>. That should disable SSL.

Comment: That's correct! Turn on everything but SSLv3. Check out the available protocols for Apache 2.4 at the link provided in answer. You can use + to turn on and - to turn off the protocols. Hope that helps!